# NodeJS ZeroMQ , no callback for send?

Tags: node.js, ipc, cluster-computing, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have multiple nodejs servers located at different locations and i need to create a IPC over tcp sockets and i am using ZeroMQ for that . I need something like request/response or pub/sub in a async way with affirmation that message is sent , but seeing the node-zeromq modules i found all the send methods are synchronous and there is no way to confirm the message the sent through a callback

In short ,
I need something like `socket.send(message,function(err,res){;});`
but i found this `socket.send(message)`

Anyone knows how to do this using ZeroMQ or any other way i could IPC reliablly and with a affirmation as response ?

**UPDATE :** Ive found https://github.com/visionmedia/axon , Axon and its req/rep send method has a callback , would be great if anyone can shed more light about this .Suggestions ?

Comment: There is nothing like affirmation that the message was sent really in ZeroMQ, all the API functions just enqueue messages to be later sent by a background thread when possible. When you need a confirmation, the other endpoint has to send it back when it receives the message. But I agree that perhaps the libraries could be written in a better way so that you can say what API call failed exactly.

Comment: axon req/res lets me do that . But im not sure if its production OK

Comment: You will probably have to try :-) But it looks like there was 1.0.0 release some 2 months ago...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the request/reply pattern instead of the pub/sub pattern with ZMQ. I believe when you make a request, there is a callback to listen for the response, as opposed to pub.send()...

Answer (score 0):

zeromq.node does yet not support reply callbacks for the `send` message.

There is an issue discussed for several years now on [GitHub](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/48) where people argue that it would be a sensible modification.

I followed the suggestion on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544612/return-value-from-zmq-socket/12566727#12566727) since I would really like to use Promises in the higher levels and therefore need callbacks for the REQ/REP mechanism. I.e. the callback is invoked from the `'message'` event handler:

```
var socket, onRepHandler, replyCallback, send;
socket = zmq.socket('req');
onRepHandler = function (reply) {
    // HACK
    // This handler is a workaround until zeromq.node supports
    // direct callback for REQ/REP:
    // https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/48
    if (replyCallback) {
        replyCallback(reply);
    }
    replyCallback = undefined;
};
socket.on('message', onRepHandler(msg));
socket.connect(address);

// Send method with callback
send = function (msg, repcb) {
    if (replyCallback) {
        throw new Error('Cannot send request before receiving reply of preceding request!');
    }
    replyCallback = repcb;
    socket.send(msg);
}
```

It feels like a questionable hack but I hope the zeromq.node library gets updated eventually.